# How to configure DbContext from a NpgSqlConnection

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, npgsql

I have a postgres database on a remote machine which has a postgres server, that I connect to using SshClient

```
using (var client = new SshClient("<public ip>", <port>, "<myuser>", "<mypassword>"))
{
    client.Connect();

    var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 5432, "10.0.0.5", 5432);
    client.AddForwardedPort(port);

    port.Start();

    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=<secret>;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=<secret>;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    port.Stop();
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Can I create a DbContext from the `NpgsqlConnection` object? I ask because I´d like to run scaffolding and all the other regular stuff, queries, commands etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. You are mixing data access technologies. The type `NpgsqlConnection` is used when you are wanting to use the [ADO.NET Technology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview). [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/) is another technology you can use for data access, and it uses the type `DbContext`. You need to decide what technology to use.

My recommendation, if you are wanting to generate the Entities and perform Linq to SQL queries, is to use Entity Framework. Entity Framework provides tools you can use for scaffolding the Database, and documentation for the Entity Framework Core toolset can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell). After installing the `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` nuget package you can run the following Scaffold command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=my_host;Database=my_db;Username=my_user;Password=my_pw" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I see. The thing is, the postgres server is on a remote computer that can only be accessed using SSH. Do you know if a DbContext can be created using a SshClient?

Comment: You should look at SSH tunneling, I believe this will solve your issue. You can setup a SSH tunnel (not in code) to make remote resources (such as a database) available locally, you would then use the EF Tools locally but targetting "localhost" instead. I would recommend reading alittle more [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/).